# dgrid column resize, hide, reorder properties gives an error if id of dgrid starts with a number

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

Following is the error: 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'addRule' on 'CSSStyleSheet': Failed to parse the rule '#742grid__Search .dgrid-column-2 { display: none; }'.
This error arises when id of the dgrid starts with a number, here it starts with 742

The same error does not show incase I change the id of my dgrid to grid_742_Search.
I think this is a bug. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML IDs cannot start with a number, per the [HTML 4.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id) spec.

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was not aware of this